# Why need not a hosted environment be provided?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

The C11 standard says:

> §5.1.2.2 **Hosted environment**
>   A hosted environment need not be provided, but shall conform to the following specifications if present.

I'm confused about it, how can I execute a program without an execution environment? Is it implied that a hosted environment is not necessary, while a freestanding environment does?

Comment: Very simply put: a hosted environment means the program runs in/under an OS. Freestanding is for writing an OS.

Comment: @Kninnug: Not only for writing an OS. Embedded systems often have not all features available required for the standard library and/or the added bloat makes no sense. And strictly speaking, gcc for instance is also just a freestanding implementation. It requires a C library like newlib or glibc.

Comment: @Kninnug If a program runs in/under an OS, we can say "It runs in a hosted environment", right? If so, why need not it be provided?

Comment: @Kninnug The definition of "hosted environment" will be helpful. I've search for it, but found nothing.

Comment: @Olaf that's why I prefixed it with 'very simply' ;). OS-writing was one of the original design goals for C though. And GCC isn't an execution environment but a translation environment (C11§5.1.1).

Comment: @Kninnug: No, gcc provides the (freestanding) [_implementation_](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.12) of the C standard. The _translation environment_ is that gcc is running in, e.g. Linux or Windows (see the link). I did not even mention the execution environment.

Comment: @Olaf fair enough, but the question *is* talking about execution environments...

Comment: @Kninnug: That was the first part for. I primarily wanted to correct/extend your statement that "Freestanding is for writing an OS". gcc was mostly supplemental information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The differentiation between a hosted and a freedstanding environment and implementation is the presence of the C standard library. Language features themselves are available for both (except for few optional features).

But **iff** an environment is called "hosted", it has to provide the full (library) features as required by the standard. There is no half-way.

A C program written for a hosted environment can expect all mandatory features to be present, thus can use `malloc`, etc. Once such a feature is missing, e.g. dynamic memory allocation, it is not a hosted environment, but a freestanding. This does not mean the latter cannot supply some of the standard libraries (or some functions of it). Actually, even for a freestanding environment there might be e.g. conversion functions avilable.

So if there is no standard library available, how can a program operate? Simply put: It does not use these functions. Instead, it has to use its own functions to access the underlying hardware or a specialised non-standard library. If you do not have a car, you have to walk, bike or build one on your own. There is no fundamental law you have to use e.g. `printf`, but can also send the characters to a serial interface directly or call the OS function to send a character to `stdout`.

Typical scenario are bare-metal (i.e. without a full-grown OS) embedded systems. They often do not need to print characters, but toogle an LED, control a motor, detect a push-button by monitoring a digital input, etc.

As others already mentioned, an OS is another example. Obviously, you cannot expect an OS to be available for the OS - there's no [turtles all the way down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down).

Comment: Is it true that any hosted environment is a freestanding environment, since the requirement of the former is more strict?

Comment: As there are some requirements for the freestanding environment more relaced, e.g. which function to call at startup and its signature, this is not **exactly** true. But, apart from those few more restrictive requirements, you can see it as a superset of the freestanding environment, yes. Just see the [standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2), this is quite clear about the requirements.

Comment: Technically an implementation that provides a `malloc` which always returns NULL could be a conforming hosted environment

Comment: @sunqingyao no, hosted means *not freestanding*. But the requirements for a freestanding implementation are a subset of those for a hosted one.

Comment: @M.M: I disagree about `malloc`. A function which by design never returns a memory block does not provide the [functionality](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.4p2) as defined by the standard, but returns a constant value. Things are [different](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.5p3) (last sentence) for `realloc`, however. So you can use a memory allocator which cannot realloc.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm confused about it, how can I execute a program without an
>   execution environment?

"Hosted" basically means with an OS underlying. Given the targets C aims to, requiring one could be very limiting, however. Consider many microcontrollers or real-time systems: the only program running is the one you coded, therefore without limitations; that's why it's said to be *free-standing*.

As N1124 says itself (emphasis mine)

> In a freestanding environment (in which C **program execution may take
>   place without any beneﬁt of an operating system**)

---

> Is it implied that a hosted environment is not necessary, while a freestanding environment does?

The standard defines the two types of environments the C code is expected to run on along with the requirements for them. Freestanding environments have lower requirements than hosted ones: this could mean that some features may not be available whereas they would instead on hosted environments, which would mean that it's "necessary" to have one.

Comment: "some features may not be available." Yes, for example without any OS `malloc` etc and `free` must be implemented in total, having already been assigned a pool of memory to work with, and without being able to request memory from an OS.

Comment: So an OS is run in a freestanding environment (provided that it is written in C and it's run on a physical machine), while a program run under/in it is run in a hosted environment?

Comment: @sunqingyao the OS does not have to be written in C. Nor does any program that runs under it (or without it).

Comment: @sunqingyao an OS need not run on a physical machine, it might run on a virtual machine. As an example, simulations on a PC of 1980s microcomputers, or more modern PICs. Layers upon layers!

Comment: @sunqingyao The _program execution_ happens in a freestanding or hosted environment. Remember that we're talking about where the C program runs and IOW whether there's an OS underlying or not. Is that helpful?

Comment: @WeatherVane And programs run in such simulations are run in a hosted environment or a freestanding environment? I think all layers are run in different hosted environments other than the bottom layer, am I right?

Comment: @sunqingyao go back to the third comment under the question itself (your comment). An OS need not be provided. If not, the program must do everything for itself, with no resources available. If there is an OS, your question quote applies. Don't get bogged down with semantics.

Answer (score 0):

Free-standing environments are used to run programs that are often quite different from the sort of thing many programs encounter.  The following would be an example of a minimal but valid C program which could perform a useful function if compiled for use on a number of PIC processors such as the PIC 16C84 which provide free-standing environments.

```
// Example of a program for a free-standing environment
int main(void)
{
  unsigned char a;
  ((unsigned char volatile*)0x86) = 3; // Set port B0 and B1 to output
  a=0;
  while(1)
  {
    ((unsigned char volatile*)0x6) |= 1; // Output high on B0
    ((unsigned char volatile*)0x6) &= ~1; // Output low on B0
    a&=127;
    b=++a;
    do
    {
      ((unsigned char volatile*)0x6) |= 2; // Output high on B1
      ((unsigned char volatile*)0x6) &= ~2; // Output low on B1
    } while(--b);
  }
}
```

If one were to compile this program and feed the resulting file into a
device programmer, that would cause the device to, any time it was powered
up, output a pulse on pin B0, then one on B1, then one on B0, two on B1,
one on B0, three on B1, etc. up to 128 on B1, and then the pattern would
repeat.

The above program wouldn't be launched by any sort of operating system--with storage for 1024 instructions and 36 bytes of
RAM there isn't really room for one.  Instead, the processor will transfer control to a small compiler-generated initialization routine that clears out RAM and then jumps to main, which must then never return.  The lack of an operating system isn't a problem, however, since all the program needs to do is wiggle a couple of I/O pins, and it can do that by writing to the addresses associated with those pins.

In practice, rather than writing code using port addresses, I would use a
compiler-supplied header file that defines names for all the I/O registers,
but the code is valid without them.  The point of interest is that the above code doesn't call any library functions for its I/O (or call any functions at all for that matter) since hardware will respond to attempts to write addresses 0x86 and 0x06 by altering the condition of some output pins, which is all this application requires.  Aside from less than a dozen instructions of compiler-generated startup code, the only code anywhere in the entire system would be the machine code generated from the above C (about 16 instructions).

Comment: Can you explain what this has to do with the difference between freestanding and hosted environments?

Comment: @M.M: The PIC example above is a freestanding environment.  If one were to feed the above code to a PIC compiler, the compiler would generate a little bit of code at address zero to clear out RAM, and aside from that the only code in the chip would be the machine code generated from the above C; most lines would translate into--literally--one instruction except that the write to 0x86 would take 4 (movlw 3 / bsf 3,5 / movwf 6 / bcf 3,5), `b=a+1` would take two (incf _a,w / movwf _b)", and `while(--b)` would take 2 (decfsz _b,f / goto LOOP).  No operating system or anything else to speak of.

Comment: @M.M: The PIC16C84 falls short of some of the implementation limits for even a freestanding C environment (e.g. I think an implementation is supposed to allow at least one function call with 128 parameters, but with 36 bytes of RAM that would be hard to satisfy), but C is still a very useful language when writing code for that platform.  On the other hand, there are no "command-line arguments" or anything of the sort, since there's nothing resembling a command line.  The application isn't launched by an OS--it's literally the only thing in the machine.

Comment: @M.M: I just edited the post.  Does that make things clearer?

Comment: Not really. On hosted implementations you can manipulate hardware resources by writing to particular addresses too (e.g. in MS-DOS, `0xB800` writes to the screen).